# Volttron bootstrap.py installation error about rabbitmq on linux virtual machine

Tags: volttron

[image: bootstrap error]

I am trying to install volttron on a linux virtual machine. I was able to install all of the requirements as well as clone the github repository. This is the error I am getting when I try to bootstrap.

I don't have a preference of rabbitmq or zeromq, and I don't have much experience with this type of program.

I have tried figuring it out by reading the docs, but have not had any success, please help me get this installed.

https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/platform-install.html

I have tried updating all of the software version. I tried editing the bootstrap file, but I am not sure what it wants me to update.

Answer (score 0):

Go for ZMQ, this does not require any additional packages, should be installed with the `python3 bootstrap.py` and you will be good to go.